# fast code for choosing array dimensions

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this segment of code

```
private int[, ,] dim(int[] m)
{

    ll = 0;
    ww = 0;
    hh = 0;           

    //  int[, ,] buff3D = new int[ll, ww, hh];
    int[, ,] to3dimen = new int[ww, ll, hh];

    if ((mm == 1) || (mm == 4) || (mm == 7))
    {
        ww = 4; ll = 8; hh = 8;
        to3dimen = new int[ww, ll, hh];
        to3dimen = To3D(m, ww, ll, hh);

    }
    else if ((mm == 2) || (mm == 5) || (mm == 8))
    {
        ww = 8; ll = 4; hh = 8;
        to3dimen = new int[ww, ll, hh];
        to3dimen = To3D(m, ww, ll, hh);
    }
    else if ((mm == 3) || (mm == 6) || (mm == 9))
    {
        ww = 8; ll = 8; hh = 4;
        to3dimen = new int[ww, ll, hh];
        to3dimen = To3D(m, ww, ll, hh);
    }

    return to3dimen;
}

private int[, ,] To3D(
    int[] thisArray, 
    int width, 
    int height, 
    int hig
)
{

    int[, ,] array3d = new int[width, height, hig];

    int sum = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < width; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < height; col++)
        {
            for (int wid = 0; wid < hig; wid++)
            {
                array3d[row, col, wid] = thisArray[sum];
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }

    return array3d;
}
```

The function `To3d` converts 1D array to 3D array and the function `dim` decides what the dimensions of the 3D array are (4,8,8 or 8,8,4 or 8,4,8).

The code works correctly, but the executing time is too long (vary based on file length).

I want a faster code if that is possible, can anyone help, please?
Note: I thought about `parallel` but that's will not be useful for my code.

Comment: If you want fast code, do not use multi-dimensional arrays. They are notoriously slow. Jagged arrays, or `C`-style arrays are recommended.

Comment: I have to use 3D array. what is the c- style array?

Comment: What is `mm` and where is it assigned a value.

Comment: @ja72 `mm` is a global variable

Comment: A `C`-style array is a `1D` array that contains in sequence the first row, then the second row, the third row etc. Doing a 3D c-style array is complex, but straight forward. Start with first page and lay the rows in sequence, and then move to the next page.

Comment: unfortunately this will not be useful for my algorithm because I need to know the dimensions of my 3D array.

Comment: You should consider renaming `sum` to `index`... Because that's what it is ;)

Comment: From what I can tell `m` is a _c_-style array which you are unpacking into a native 3D array.

Comment: Since you are using globals, you may consider using another global `arrayType`, which could be enumerated as `0`, `1`, or `2`, depending on which if-condition is evaluated to true in `dim`.

Comment: See my answer to get the dimensions quickly.

Comment: See my answer to do this with  a _c_-style array and not a 3D array.

Comment: @Yussra - C# doesn't have global variables.

Comment: @Enigmativity - The _OP_ style reminds me of `Fortran` because array dimensions are initialized ahead of use. And when he mentioned global variables, I went bingo!.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of superfluous code here. You only need *one* assignment to `to3dimen` that should happen inside the `To3D()` function.

But that is not what is slowing you down. What is slowing you down is the use of multi-dimensional arrays.

For starters, clean up `Dim()` as

```
private int[,,] Dim(int[] m)
{

    // mm   ww  ll  hh      offset=(mm-1)%3
    //  1   4   8   8       0
    //  2   8   4   8       1
    //  3   8   8   4       2
    //  4   4   8   8       0
    //  5   8   4   8       1
    //  6   8   8   4       2
    //  7   4   8   8       0
    //  8   8   4   8       1
    //  9   8   8   4       2

    int offset = (mm - 1) % 3;
    int ww = offset == 0 ? 4 : 8;
    int ll = offset == 1 ? 4 : 8;
    int hh = offset == 2 ? 4 : 8;

    return To3D(m, ww, ll, hh);

}
```

But to harness the power of [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) you should create a class the packs or unpacks the three coordinates into a single array index. Consider the following sample code:

```
public class Packed3dArray : IEnumerable<int>
{
    readonly int width, height, hig;
    readonly int[] array;

    public Packed3dArray(int[] array, int mm)
    {
        int offset = (mm - 1) % 3;
        this.width = offset == 0 ? 4 : 8;
        this.height = offset == 1 ? 4 : 8;
        this.hig = offset == 2 ? 4 : 8;
        this.array = array;
    }
    #region Properties
    public int Width => width;
    public int Height => height;
    public int Hig => hig;
    public int Index(int row, int col, int wid) => wid + hig*(col + height*row);

    /// <summary>
    /// Default indexer with three coordinates
    /// </summary>
    public int this[int row, int col, int wid]
    {
        // this is really fast because it is integer math
        // and accesses a 1D array which is recommended.
        get => array[wid + hig*(col + height*row)];
        set => array[wid + hig*(col + height*row)] = value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default indexer with an index
    /// </summary>
    public int this[int index] 
    {
        get => array[index];
        set => array[index]=value;
    }

    #endregion
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return array[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

to be used as

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[8 * 8 * 4];
    // Use mm=3
    Packed3dArray pa = new Packed3dArray(array, 3);
    int width = pa.Width    // width = 8
    int height = pa.Height  // height = 8
    int hig = pa.Hig        // hig = 4    

    // Set the last element to one using the default indexer (see code).
    pa[7, 7, 3] = 1;
    // or read a value
    var x = pa[255];  // x=1

    // Go through all the elements and unpack the (x,y,z) values into an index:
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++)
        {
            for (int wid = 0; wid < 4; wid++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"[{row},{col},{wid}]=[{pa.Index(row, col, wid)}]={pa[row,col,wid]}");
            }
        }
    }

    // Recover the original array by using Enumerable.ToArray() extension
    int[] copy = pa.ToArray();
}
```

The result is:

```
[0,0,0]=[0]=0
[0,0,1]=[1]=0
[0,0,2]=[2]=0
[0,0,3]=[3]=0
[0,1,0]=[4]=0
[0,1,1]=[5]=0
...
[0,7,3]=[31]=0
[1,0,0]=[32]=0
[1,0,1]=[33]=0
...
[4,7,2]=[158]=0
[4,7,3]=[159]=0
[5,0,0]=[160]=0
[5,0,1]=[161]=0
...
[7,6,3]=[251]=0
[7,7,0]=[252]=0
[7,7,1]=[253]=0
[7,7,2]=[254]=0
[7,7,3]=[255]=1
```

Comment: The corresponding coordinate is returned with the `Index()` function. Like `k = pa.Index(row, col, wid)`. I have edited the code to allow access to the array, with one index or with three.

Answer (score 0):

I think your nested for-loops evaluate to something like O(n^3) time, so it definitely will slow down with larger files.

You might achieve a slightly faster, but much more ugly, result with this modification:

```
for (int row = 0; row++ < width;)
{
    for (int col = 0; col++ < height;)
    {
        for (int wid = 0; wid++ < hig;)
        {
            array3d[row, col, wid] = thisArray[sum++];
        }
    }
}
```

This is isn't much different than slapping a (crappy) turbo-charger in a Ford Escort. It will be slightly faster, but never cool ;)

Mind you, it's ***still*** O(n^3).

Comment: You code is also `O(n^3)` but the fastest changing index `wid` should correspond to the memory location where values are sequential. Your code reduces memory cache misses.

Comment: @ja72 Thanks, I'll clarify that it is still O(n^3). I knew that, but I thought that was implicitly clear. I'll edit the answer it's more obvious.

Comment: @Yussra I ran my loop as it it written above, and didn’t receive an out-of-bounds error. Are you sure you did exactly what I wrote? (My original array was populated with exactly the amount of elements created by the 3d array however.)